# Selecting Specific Date in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am trying to make the date coming from service as default date and selected also in a uidatepicker. I have tried something, but it is not working.

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setYear:[[tempBirthDate substringToIndex:4] integerValue]];
    [components setMonth:[[tempString substringFromIndex:5] integerValue]];
    [components setDay:[[tempBirthDate substringFromIndex:8] integerValue]];
    NSDate *defualtDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [datePicker setDate:defualtDate];
```

What am i missing?

Could you please help me to figure it out?

for instance : values are coming from the service as 03/19/1986

and i want it selected by picker.

Comment: Show us your sample values you received from service and the expected output

Comment: Why dont you use NSDateformatter instead of     [components setYear:[[tempBirthDate substringToIndex:4] integerValue]]; blah blah....

Answer (score 3):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:[[tempBirthDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 4)] integerValue]];
[components setMonth:[[tempBirthDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] integerValue]];
[components setDay:[[tempBirthDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 2)] integerValue]];
NSDate *defualtDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
[datePicker setDate:defualtDate];
```

Comment: Did you have any error? what is the value of defaultDate before you set it to datePicker given your tempBirthDate of '03/19/1986'?

Comment: Did you try copying this code and replacing your code? or just copied the NSMakeRange... part? In your code above you can see there is tempString... where did this come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSDateFormatter` for placing date in to the date picker:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateFromServer];
[datePicker setDate:date];
```